# Issue with float lower than 1

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I've got a very strange issue on pine script v4. My variables lower than 1 are considered like 0 :-(

For exemple :

```
myConst = 14
myVariable = 2 / (myConst + 1) //the result is 0.1333333
plot(100 / myVariable)
```

This code return me an error at the last line : "Division by zero"

I tried that too, but with no effects

```
float myVariable = 2 / (myConst + 1)
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: It looks like `2 / (myConst + 1)` is an integer division. Have you tried `2.0 / (myConst + 1)` instead?

Comment: The "funny" thing is, I have this issue only when the result is lower than 1.
In this 2 example, the first one work well, but I have the issue on the second (and need to tweak) :

myVariable1 = (100/30) - 1 --> is working
myVariable2 = (100/70) - 1  --> Dont work and need to replace to myVariable2 = (100/70.0) - 1

Comment: Please don't use the `script` tag. It means *nothing at all*. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. The tag is so bad it will was deleted in the past and is going to be deleted again very soon